# Error when I select command to view: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'XYZ' to data type int."

Tags: sql, view

> "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'XYZ' to data type int."

hello, this error occurs when the created view select command is made. where do i make mistakes?

```
SELECT Firm = '4', *
FROM CRT.TANKER.DBO.tbl_SparePart 
UNION ALL
SELECT Firm = '3', *
FROM CRT_BULK.BULK.DBO.tbl_SparePart
```

Comment: Does the view adds an integer ID column?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That syntax is not ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: @jarlh: actually `Firm = '4'` **is** ANSI SQL - it's a boolean expression that returns `true` or `false` if the column `firm` contains the (string) value `'4'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, that part is fine, but you can't combine it (or anything else) with a single `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Any Column From `CRT.TANKER.DBO.tbl_SparePart` Table is having `int` datatype and Column From `CRT_BULK.BULK.DBO.tbl_SparePart` Table At same position may have `nvarchar` type of data or vice versa that's why you are getting this error. Because **one column can have only one type of data** so you need to cast your column to `string` type

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `Firm =` but you rvalue and an alias

```
  SELECT  '4' FIrm, *
  FROM CRT.TANKER.DBO.tbl_SparePart 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '3', *
  FROM CRT_BULK.BULK.DBO.tbl_SparePart
```